# Show that if $[\mathbb Q(\cos\theta,\cos\frac{\theta}{3}):\mathbb Q(\cos \theta)]=1$, then $\theta$ can be trisected using straightedge and compass.

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, geometric-construction

Show that if $[\mathbb Q(\cos\theta,\cos\frac{\theta}{3}):\mathbb Q(\cos \theta)]=1$, then $\theta$ can be trisected using straightedge and compass.

**Proof**: Clearly $\mathbb Q(\cos\theta,\cos\frac{\theta}{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\cos\theta)$, hence $\cos\frac{\theta}{3}\in\mathbb{Q}(\cos\theta)$, meaning $\cos\frac{\theta}{3}$ can be obtained from the elements of $\mathbb{Q}\cup \{\cos\theta\}$ by a finite sequence of additions, subtractions, multiplications and taking inverses. Screeching halt.

**My question**: Clearly I want to show that $\cos\frac{\theta}{3}$ is an element of $\mathbb{Q}(P)^{py}$, where $P:=\{0 ,1, \cos\theta\}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(P)^{py}$ is the Pythagorean closure of $\mathbb{Q}(P)$, because then it follows immediately that $\cos\frac{\theta}{3}$ is constructible from $P$; but the following theorem

"A complex number $\alpha$ is an element of $\mathbb{Q}(P)^{py}$ IFF there is a tower of field extensions $\mathbb{Q}(P)=K_0\subset K_1 \subset \dots \subset K_n=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ such that $[K_{j+1}: K_j]=2$ for $0\leq j\leq n-1$"

clearly contradicts the result I wish to prove. What did I miss?

A related question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/210520/506332); but the answer omitted the details I need. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "which clearly contradicts the result I wish to prove" -- Why do you say this?  In your context, the tower of extensions has $n=0$, so it holds vacuously: not a contradiction.

Comment: @Brain Moehring because I was unsure about that, since $[K_1: K_0]=1\neq 2$.

Comment: The point is that there is no $K_1$.  The "tower" is $\mathbb{Q}(P) = K_0 = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I see. Thank you for the confirmation!